# Parsing a tab delimited text file

Tags: c++, ifstream, getline, text-parsing

I'm trying to parse a text file from one format to another. The text file is delimited by tabs. The text file I'm using as test has as of now three types of lines. For example, the first line of the text file has an H in the beginning. Since I do not need it now, I ignore it and pass to the next line. Similarly, I have lines that start with S and L. The S lines have five strings, including the first character, which are read by:

`while(std:: ifstream readFile >> string1 >> string2 >> string3)`

Below this `while` I have an `if` statement to check every S at the beginning of each line, which is as follows:

`if(string1[string1.length()-1]=='S')`

Then I print in the console each value to make sure every line which has an S is being printed in the console, but it's not. It's showing `n - 2` where `n = total of lines containing S at the beginning`. I should also mention that below `print` statement, I also have this: `std::getline(readFile, string1);` without this, it shows me `n - 5`, if I'm not mistaken.

Also, when I only use two parameters while instead of three, all lines are shown with the first two strings, but as soon as I pass three parameters it changes back to `n - 2`.

What could be the problem that whenever I pass more than two parameters, it does not show me every line that contain S at the beginning(specifically the first two).

Thanks, and sorry if not explicit enough.

Comment: Are you sure this is your real code?  Your `while` statement doesn't look right at all, and your `if` statement seems to be checking the last character in the line, not the first.

Comment: The `while` statement is actually like this `while(readFile >> state >> nodes >> sequence)` The `if` statement works checking the first character so far, but it's not showing the first two line. `if(state[state.length()-1]=='S')` I should also mention, readFIle is a ifstream object.

Comment: Do you mind giving a minimal code? Also your if statement is not checking the first character.It is checking the last character of string1.

Comment: Do you mean `S`,`H` and `L` act as some labels to identify the sentences or are they the first character of the first word of the sentence?

Comment: You said S lines have 5 strings, including the string that starts with S. But your `while` statement only reads 3. So the next line read would be the remaining strings of the S line and the succeeding strings. For example, S line contains `S<tab>1<tab>2<tab>3<tab>4`, the `while` statement will only read S, 1 and 2. When it goes back to that statement, it will read 3, 4 and the first string on the next line.

Comment: When you read a file as in your while loop, it reads first word,say word1, to string1, word2 to string2 and word3 to string3. Then again word4 to string1, word5 to string2 and so on, irrespective of which line it belongs to.

Comment: @Jackzz `S` are a single character, but still declared as a string. That's why it checks correctly inside `if(state[state.length()-1]=='S')`since inside the string there's only one character. Yes, the `S`, `H`, and `L` are the labels to identify what each sentence is and what then is needed to do.

Comment: @Rowen It's true, there's 5 strings, including the first string which consist of a single character, in the long run I do need to store these strings properly, but not now. For now I am only interested in the first three, the first one becuase is the label, second string it has the number of the node and the third string because it contains the string associated with said node. Furthermore, when I try to capture all five string, nothing is being captured, neither being printed out in the console nor in the binary with format specifified.

Comment: @Jackzz Didn't read the part about the minimal code. Sure, well firstly, the `main` creates an instance of the   class which resides almost all of the code. After the instance is created, the object is used to call the only function that there is in `main`. The function has a single parameter, the name of the file to be opened(it is not prompted, it's just a string being passed into the function.) Then, the function starts with an `if` `statement` `if(readFile.is_open())` below the `if` is the `while` that i showed and right after that the other `if statement`. Have a `cout` to make sure...

Comment: [cont.]evertything is being captured. In the next line, I have this `std::getline(readFile, state);` I do not understand why, but when I do not use the getline, it results in less lines being capture, instead of the first two that I'm currently missing when using it like now.

Comment: It's only by chance that `std::getline()` results in more S lines being captured. Since the number of strings vary depending on the `state` string, you shouldn't use the `>>` operator. Trace your code and see what's being put to string1 to string3 to confirm this. It's better to use `std::getline()` in `while()`, get the `state` string, and depending on that, get the rest of the strings.

Comment: @Rowen The number of string in 'S' lines is a constant, which is five. The 'L' have too a constant of 6 strings. I have the 'while' set up to capture only the first three string. Inside the while i have an 'if' to check the 'state string' equals to 'S' after this i have a 'cout' with all three strings variable to trace what they have in each iterarion.  Then 'getline', then I have two other funcions that make the parse, but since i havent gotten the capture right i have not worried to nuch about this. I'll try instead like you said and post the results, thank you.

Comment: @Rowen Forgot to mention, I found a solution. Instead of the method I was using, I used an sstream to capture each string identified in each line. Similar to before, I have an `if statement` to chech each line that starts with an `S` but instead of this `while(readFile >> state >> nodes >> sequence)` I changed it to while(readFile >> state)` right after I have: `getline(readFile, line);` and `setState(line);`. In my setState function I then use the `string line` to create a `sstream object` with it, identify each string in that line and assign it to a variable. This solved my problem.